# Javascript function loops too many times and returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON data in this format

```
"Sensor": "14829304",
    "DATA": {
        "Rainfall": {
            "2022-01-11": {
                "T1": {
                    "MM": "3.94",
                    "CONFIRMED": "T"
                },
                "T2": {
                    "MM": "3.91",
                    "CONFIRMED": "T"
                }
              }
            },
     "Temperature": {
            "2022-01-11": {
                "T1": {
                    "MM": "9.32",
                    "CONFIRMED": "T"
                },
                "T2": {
                    "MM": "9.44",
                    "CONFIRMED": "T"
                }
              }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to sum up all of the MM for rainfall grouped by date. The problem is, my attempt isn't looping over all of the dates once, but loops over how many days there are.

My attempt is

```
let groupedDay = {};

const dailyRainfall = Object.entries(weatherdata.DATA.Rainfall).forEach(([day, times]) => {
        if (groupedDay[day] == null) groupedDay[day] = 0
        Object.values(times).forEach(data => {
            if (data.MM != null) groupedDay[day] += parseFloat(data.MM)
        })
        //console.log(groupedDay)
        return groupedDay
     })

console.log(dailyRainfall)
```

The other problem I have is that the function returns undefined, but I can console log the groupedDay inside the function. I want it to return:

```
{ '2022-01-11': xxxx,
  '2022-01-12': yyyy,
  '2022-01-13': zzzz
}
```

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: `forEach` always returns `undefined`

Comment: That is a malformed JavaScript object not JSON

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't realise it always returns undefined - I'll look at that.

Sorry, I'm calling an API and it said it was JSON format

At the moment I'm calling it on page load

Comment: Your code will work as is, but your output is inside `groupedDay` instead of `dailyRainfall`.  Often this kind of grouping is done via `Array.reduce`, if you want the pattern `const myOutput = someArray.someFunc(...)`

Comment: Something probably? does the parsing from JSON (which is a string) into a JavaScript objected given your comment.  It might help here to add a well formed sample.  From you description the values under ` "Temperature":` are not in scope here..  What is unclear is how the other dates in the output example come into play given your sample data.

Comment: Thanks, I did try reduce at first but struggled to make it work. I'll have another go at it

Comment: Can you post the real json pls? I can see only one record  and I don't see any arrays at all. What about Sensor number is it only one and how dates depends on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `forEach` returns undefined, even if the callback function returns something. The correct way is not `console.log(dailyRainfall)` but `console.log(groupedDay)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the groupedDay after you are done witht he data, forEach does not have a return value, it will always be undefined

```js
const data = {"Sensor": "14829304","DATA": {"Rainfall": {
"2022-01-11": {"T1": {"MM": "1","CONFIRMED": "T"},"T2": {"MM": "1","CONFIRMED": "T"}},
"2022-01-12": {"T1": {"MM": "2","CONFIRMED": "T"},"T2": {"MM": "2","CONFIRMED": "T"}},
"2022-01-13": {"T1": {"MM": "3","CONFIRMED": "T"},"T2": {"MM": "3","CONFIRMED": "T"}}},
"Temperature": {"2022-01-11": {"T1": {"MM": "9.32","CONFIRMED": "T"},"T2": {"MM": "9.44","CONFIRMED": "T"}}}}}

let groupedDay = {};

Object.entries(data.DATA.Rainfall).forEach(([day, times]) => {
        if (groupedDay[day] == null) groupedDay[day] = 0
        
        Object.values(times).forEach(data => {
            if (data.MM != null) groupedDay[day] += parseFloat(data.MM)
        })
     })

console.log(groupedDay)
```